# How to loop mount an iso in raspberry pi?

Tags: mount

I'm trying to do:

```
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt/ubuntu
```

and getting:

`unknown filesystem type 'iso9660'`

Doing a:
`uname -a` on my pi reveals:

```
Linux pi 4.14.79+ #1159 Sun Nov 4 17:28:08 GMT 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Running `sudo modprobe iso9660` reveals:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.14.79+/modules.dep.bin'
```

`modprobe: FATAL: Module iso9660 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.79+`

How can I loop-back mount the above iso in my Pi?

Comment: my pi is also a tftp server from where i netboot my ubuntu installs. i want to loop-back mount the iso so my installs are faster than downloading base files directly from the internet. see "from a local server" section here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet @JaromandaX

Comment: Sorry, my bad ... `isofs` is what you'll want - i.e. `modprobe isofs`

Comment: I don't think the stock kernel has the library. getting, "modprobe: FATAL: Module isofs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.79+"

Comment: `isofs.ko` is part of `raspberrypi-kernel` package so it must be there if you have raspbian installed, so check `/lib/modules/4.14.79+/kernel/fs/isofs` folder

Comment: Interesting. Here's my folder - `/lib/modules/4.14.98+/kernel/fs/isofs`. (note `98+` instead of `79+` modprobe is reporting). There's no `/lib/modules/4.14.79+` folder.

Comment: well, you've done something really funky if you have the latest modules, but a previous kernel - have you upgraded recently without rebooting the pi? hint: try rebooting the pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
sudo modprobe isofs
```

That should load support for iso9660